# Save profile picture associated with the user on Firebase

Tags: ios, image, firebase, photo, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase for iOS
on my app the user has to associate a photo with his profile
on MySQL there is BLOB type to save images inside the database
but on Firebase I don't find such a thing

Comment: If you want to save a profile image for the current users, Firebase supports that. See my answer for details. If it' just storing images, there's a link in my answer to Firebase storage for that task.

Answer (score 3):

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic, 0.5) else {return}
        let profileImgReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_image_urls").child("\(uid).png")
        let uploadTask = profileImgReference.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString ?? ""
                // Here you get the download url of the profile picture.
            }
        }
        uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.progress?.fractionCompleted ?? "")
            // Here you can get the progress of the upload process.
        })
```

Step 1: convert your UIImage to Jpeg Data or PNG Data by using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage, compressionQuality)` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage)`

Step 2: Create a storage reference. In the above example I have used `Storage.storage().reference()` to get the storage reference of the current Firebase app and then I am creating a folder by using `.child("FolderName")`

Step 3: Use Firebase Storage's `.putData` function for upload the image data to firebase storage. You can capture the task reference (ie. uploadTask) for observing the progress of the upload.

// Note: I am using the Firebase user ID as the image name because every user id is unique for firebase Auth and there is no mismatch in profile picture replacing or getting deleted accidently.

Comment: `profileImgReference.downloadURL { url, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Firebase Storage` to upload the image, and then get the URL and save the URL somewhere in your database.

Here's the documentation on how to upload files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

Here's an example from one of my projects

```
FIRStorageReference *ref = [[[FIRStorage storage] reference] child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/users/profilesPictures/pp%@.jpg", [UsersDatabase currentUserID]]];
[ref putData:imageData metadata:nil completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * _Nullable metadata, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        [[self viewController] hideFullscreenLoading];
        [[self viewController] showError:error];
    } else {
        [ref downloadURLWithCompletion:^(NSURL * _Nullable URL, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                [[self viewController] hideFullscreenLoading];
                [[self viewController] showError:error];
            } else {
                [[self viewController] hideFullscreenLoading];
                [self.profilePictureButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [[UsersDatabase sharedInstance].currentUser setProfilePictureURL:[URL absoluteString]];
                [UsersDatabase saveCurrentUser]; // This also updates the user's data in the realtime database.
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this is super simple task.

A Firebase user object has a photoUrl property which can be read like this

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

The URL can be one that's external to Firebase or kept in [Firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files)

To change the photoUrl:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = //if you want to change the displayName
changeRequest?.photoURL = //some Url
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```